# install Ubuntu and remove Windows 7

Tags: system-installation

I'm using Windows 7 on my laptop (2GB RAM, 250 GB HDD). I want to install Ubuntu and remove Windows 7. I have Partitioned my laptop into 2 partitions: , C Drive - 105 GB and D Drive - 145 GB. I want to install Ubuntu on C drive 
             *All my data in D drive * no backup*

I have already selected the "Try something else option "

```
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdb1 ntfs        104855 MB unknown  C drive
/dev/sdb5 ntfs        145192 MB unknown  D drive
```

I **need help** using the "Try Something Else" Option

My course of action:

laptop power on >>boot>>>>>>>>>ubuntu >>next>>something else>>partition.

Answer (score 1):

- Click he 'Do Something Else' option
- You will be presented with graphical layout of partitions on your hard drive.
- Double click `/dev/sdb1`
  You will now be presented with a dialog box. Select "Ext4 Journaling system" in 'Use as'dropdown menu
- In the 'Mount Point' Dialog, select '`/`'
- Make sure 'Format this partition' checkbox is selected.
- Now click OK and continue with installation. Click 'Install Now' to start installing
  If it says something about swap, just ignore it.

Comment: Please mark as solved if it really solves your problem

Comment: still detecting file  systems ........

Comment: how long it will take to complete?

Comment: still detecting file systems ......